# How do I send an arbitrary message with SoapUI?

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I'm trying to implement a web service based on a very complex WSDL.  I know how to use SoapUI to import a WSDL and create tests based on it, but when I try to import this one with SoapUI, it fails and gives me a meaningless Java error message.

That shouldn't be an issue, though.  It ought to be a trivial task for any halfway decent tool to execute an arbitrary, user-defined command.  I have a sample SOAP message already prepared, and I want to use SoapUI to send it to my server.  Unfortunately, no matter how many layers of batch-this and testcase-that I dig through, I can't find the "send arbitrary SOAP message" command anywhere.

I find it difficult to believe that a tool like this wouldn't have one at all, so I figure I'm just missing something. Does anyone know the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can send an arbitrary SOAP Message to a Web Service. If its doc-literal based service it will be expecting a SOAP Message which is adhering to schema. So the SOAP Message has to be valid.